# Indian Snake Species Identification

Tags: zoology, species-identification, herpetology, snake

Location: southern India

**Time**: noon
**Approx. Size**:
*Length:* around 2 feet; 
*Size*: extremely small, like a straw.
*Diameter*: less than 1 cm.
Was very fast in climbing aisle of mud bed/uphill like 90 degree accent.
[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Ashok's Bronzeback** (*Dendrelaphis ashoki*).

[image: Ashok's Bronzeback]

This is a relatively small snake (typically [70 cm](http://www.indiansnakes.org/content/ashoks-bronzeback) in length) that feeds on lizards, frogs and small rodents.

More information can be found [here](http://www.indiansnakes.org/content/ashoks-bronzeback) or [here](http://reptile-database.reptarium.cz/species?genus=Dendrelaphis&species=ashoki).

It's range is Southwestern India:

[image]

You can differentiate this species from closely related [*D. girii*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendrelaphis_girii) based on it having a longer "postocular" black line than *D. ashoki* -- in *D. ashoki* it stops shortly caudal to the eye (e.g., see [here](http://www.indiansnakes.org/content/giris-bronzeback)).

Comment: +1 its like 100% close i would say, Only the bluish shiny thing makes me think, it might be very close family one.

Comment: @Umar I'm glad you added the third photo showing the blue shimmer of your specimen! That gives me even more confidence that this is your species. (the blue is only visible in certain positions -- again see [here](http://www.indiansnakes.org/content/ashoks-bronzeback).

Comment: muahuhhaa i am seeing the blue stripes after you mentioned it (in the third photo)

Comment: Dumb question: When the differences are so minor (e.g. "longer "postocular" black line") what's the reason for designating them as two different species?

Comment: @curious_cat feel free to ask this in a new question. Comments aren't the best place for extended  discussion of additional questions.